# How do I know that my own beliefs about my motivations are accurate?

Tags: motivation, belief, causal-inference

When someone performs an action, they generally have a belief about why they are doing it (E.g. “I am going upstairs to pick up my headphones”).

These beliefs do not necessarily translate into observables - e.g. you may go upstairs to pick up headphones, forget what you were planning, and pick up a phone charger instead.

How does one *know* that they actually for example forgot, though, rather than simply having had false beliefs about their motives?

I have heard of cases where split brain patients give nonsensical responses to such questions when actions are performed by the side of the brain not responsible for speech. How does one know they are not doing the same thing all the time, just more subtly?

Unsure about tags, apologies if incorrect.